# Jenkins Pipeline checkout and build on remote Docker host from Bitbucket commit

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to trigger a job via Bitbucket commit where the source is checked out and built in a remote Docker host with a custom docker builder image using Jenkins pipeline script. However this is proving to be very challenging. Here is what I have so far.

```
node {
    stage('Source checkout') {
        checkout([$class: 'GitSCM',
            branches: [[name: '*/master']],
            doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
            extensions: [],
            submoduleCfg: [],
            userRemoteConfigs: [[
                credentialsId: 'bitbucket-jenkins-key',
                url: 'ssh://bitbucket.test.com:7999/test/app.git'
            ]]])
    }

    stage('Build image') {
        dockerNode(credentialsId: '',
        dockerHost: 'tcp://docker.test.com:2376',
        image: 'test/builder:generic', remoteFs: '/home/jenkins') {
            sh 'docker build -t test/app:$BUILD_NUMBER -f .'
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Why ... why do you have to check-out as part of the script? Usually, a Jenkins job will check out the project, find the JenkinsFile, then build it.

Comment: I wasn't sure what the best practice was. I changed it to run the Jenkinsfile script from the webhook invoked checkout. However, it's still the same issue, where the remote docker builder container that is spun up does not have the checked out source. I can't seem to find a way to copy the source into the container. The container is based on the Jenkins docker slave image, so I had assumed it would just work.